# CakePHP joins are not showing all data for N-to-M query

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-3.0

what I am trying to do is a simple N-to-M join as you know it from SQL.
The tables are structured the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `lastname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `groups_users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

When it now comes to the query, I want to have rows containing all date from the user correlated with groups.
So in my understanding I have to go to the UserController and perform the following two left joins (users into groups_users and groups_users into groups)

```
$query2 = $this->Users->find();
$query2->join([
    'a' => [
        'table' => 'groups_users',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => [
            'a.user_id' => 'users.id',
            'users.id' => 1
        ]
    ],
    'b' => [
        'table' => 'groups',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => [
            'b.id' => 'a.group_id'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

And of course here are my test data:

```
INSERT INTO `customytest`.`users` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `password`, `image`, `role_id`) VALUES (NULL, 'nm1', 'fn1', 'ln1', 'doesnt matter', NULL, '');
INSERT INTO `customytest`.`users` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `password`, `image`, `role_id`) VALUES (NULL, 'nm2', 'fn2', 'ln2', 'doesnt matter', NULL, '');
INSERT INTO `customytest`.`users` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `password`, `image`, `role_id`) VALUES (NULL, 'nm3', 'fn3', 'ln3', 'doesnt matter', NULL, '');

INSERT INTO `customytest`.`groups` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 'group1');

INSERT INTO `customytest`.`groups_users` (`id`, `group_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `customytest`.`groups_users` (`id`, `group_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO `customytest`.`groups_users` (`id`, `group_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, 1, 3);
```

As a result I only get the data for users and not the correlated groups data:

```
{"id":1,"firstname":"nm1","lastname":"fn1","username":"ln1","password":"doesnt matter","image":null,"role_id":0},
{"id":2,"firstname":"nm2","lastname":"fn2","username":"ln2","password":"doesnt matter","image":null,"role_id":0},
{"id":3,"firstname":"nm3","lastname":"fn3","username":"ln3","password":"doesnt matter","image":null,"role_id":0}
```

Comment: Did you use bake to generate your models and controllers? If your [model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) are set up correctly, you shouldn't need to do any manual joining in the query, but rather just use `$this->Users->find()->contain(['Groups']);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the high level ORM, so I'd suggest to use the appropriate functionality that does the matching and stitching for you. Specifically, `Query::contain()`, this will join in the related data, and also hydrate the results properly, so that you end up with consitent result sets, and non-duplicate data.

That's pretty much CakePHP 101, so I'd suggest that study the docs a little closer before going into trial and error mode. Given that you have properly set up the associations, your query would reduce to

```
$this->Users
    ->find()
    ->contain('Groups')
    ->where([
        'Users.id' => 1
    ]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Retrieving Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Eager Loading Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations)**

Manual joins may of course be used too, but this should ideally only be necessary for really complicated queries and similar edge cases. However, for the sake of completeness, the setup for a query with manual joins should look more like this:

```
$this->Users
    ->find()
    ->select($this->Users)
    ->select(['b.id', 'b.name'])
    ->join([
        'a' => [
            'table' => 'groups_users',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => [
                'a.user_id = users.id'
            ]
        ],
        'b' => [
            'table' => 'groups',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => [
                'b.id = a.group_id'
            ]
        ]
    ])
    ->where([
        'Users.id' => 1
    ]);
```

With manual joins, you have to specifiy the fields that should be selected. And since you are not following the naming conventions, you have to specify them one by one. If you would follow the conventions, and proper associations would exists (which makes such use of manual joins superfluous), you could use `select($this->Users->Groups)` instead - the joins would look like:

```
'GroupsUsers' => [
    'table' => 'groups_users',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => [
        'GroupsUsers.user_id = Users.id'
    ]
],
'Groups' => [
    'table' => 'groups',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => [
        'Groups.id = GroupsUsers.group_id'
    ]
]
```

Also notice the non-usage of key/value conditions, this is required as otherwise you'd compare against strings, like `a.user_id = 'users.id'`, which of course won't work. Also if you plan to restrict things to a specific user, there should be no need for an additional condition for the join table, as the user id comparision already filters things as required.

And last but not least, you may receive duplicate data this way when a user is in more than one group, so that's another reason why you shouldn't do things like this manually, `Query::contain()` will handle things way more gracefully.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Joins](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)**

Comment: you couldnt have answered more in detail! thank you :)